# Improving the performance of maximal square problem

Tags: python, algorithm, search, multidimensional-array, convolution

This question is about [problem #221 from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-square/).

Essentially, we look for the largest square of `1`s in a `2d` binary grid. I'm sure there are a lot of standard search algorithms for these problems, but since I'm unaware of them, I came up with a completely unique idea.

---

The idea is that we convolve the given array with kernels of sizes `(1,1),(2,2),...` whose elements are all ones and mark the indices where the convolution yields full sum(`n^2, when kernel is (n,n)`). We then selectively convolve(basically the Hadamard product) these indices with the next kernel `(n+1,n+1)`. We repeat this until the number of indices is 1, which means we found our maximal square.

Here is the full program

```
import numpy as np
class Solution:
    def maximalSquare(self, matrix: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        matrix=[[int(j) for j in i] for i in matrix]
        shap=np.shape(matrix)
        if np.all([matrix,np.ones(shap)]):
            return min(shap[0],shap[1])**2
        s=list(enumerate(range(max(shap[0],shap[1])+1)))[1:]
        indices=list(np.ndindex(shap))
        def convolution(m,k,ind):
            n=len(k)
            m=np.pad(m,[n,n],mode='constant')
            mm=np.copy(m)
            for i in ind:
                m[i[0]+n,i[1]+n]=np.sum(np.multiply(mm[i[0]+1:i[0]+1+n,i[1]+1:i[1]+1+n],k))
            indices=list(np.where(m==n**2))
            return [(indices[0][i]-n,indices[1][i]-n) for i in range(len(indices[0]))]

        for i in s:
            kernel=np.ones(i)
            indices=convolution(matrix,kernel,indices)
            if len(indices)==1:
                return i[0]**2
            elif len(indices)==0:
                return (i[0]-1)**2
```

---

To my surprise, this actually works really well. The worst case is when all of the input matrix's elements are ones. The worst case of a `300x300` matrix takes `2m50s` to compile.

I don't think the math can be simplified more. Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Even if you implement this algorithm well, taking advantage of the separability of the kernels and using FFT convolution, it takes O(n^3 log n) for an n x n matrix.   A simple and efficient algorithm for this problem takes O(n^2).  You should be expecting less than a millisecond for a 300x300 matrix, even in python.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thanks for the comment. Can you please elaborate on how you concluded the time complexity? As I mentioned in the question, we discard indices which do not matter to us continuously, which I believe should reduce the time.

Comment: discarding those indices doesn't affect the worst case complexity.  A separable n x n FFT convolution is 2n 1D convolutions, and each takes O(n log n) time.  You need to do up to n of those, one for each kernel size.  That's O(n^3 log n) all together.  But what I really want you to take away from this discussion is the value of reading before you write, and listening before you talk. Even for a simple problem like this, a lot of thought has already been put into it by a lot of people who then wrote down stuff you can learn from.

Comment: If you want to keep this in DSP-land just for fun, you can do your convolutions with separable integrator-comb filters (linear time) and binary search to find the largest size kernel that works, for O(n^2 log n) time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans yes, I agree that there are much better solutions already out there. I'm sure there are many that can immediately bash out the fastest standard search implementations and be done with the problem. I came up with an alternate solution, which although suboptimal, does work. I really think I learned a thing or two while implementing my own technique. As someone starting out with competitive programming, I find this very difficult to digest, the fact that we not just seek a solution but one that is highly performant too, and there are only few standard ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'll definitely learnt these better techniques too. Thanks for the elaboration and I'll look more on those DSP suggestions you gave.